# Heating zone not working when other 2 do

Tags: heating, baseboard, forced-air

I have three zones of forced air/baseboard heating in my house.  I had the furnace shut off for the summer and after turning it back on, two zones in the house work and one does not.  Any tips on how to troubleshoot the problem?  The simplest problem (my guess) it could be (other than gas pipes being shut off) is the thermostat is working properly.  Is there anyway to bypass the thermostat to see if that is the issue.  Re: gas pipes being shut off, I have checked that and all seem to be on/flowing.

Comment: Forced air and baseboard are generally different heating types - what do you actually have? If it somehow actually can be described as you have described it, please describe it in more detail, as it would be "unusual" to say the least.

Comment: What is the make and model furnace/boiler?  Is there a zone controller?  If so, what is the make and model?

Comment: Is it a single furnace/boiler, or are there seperate heating systems in each zone?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.  I'll try to answer all.  It is definitely baseboard, not forced air.  I'll have to get back on the make/model of the furnace, but it is a single furnace with three zone controlling switches, all three are set to "AUTO"

Comment: So it's a boiler?

Comment: As a simple test for the thermostat, you can short the wire attached to the `R` terminal to the wire attached to the `W` terminal. This will tell the furnace/boiler that the thermostat is cold.